# How do I apply a string function to a table column?

Tags: php, arrays, string, mysql

As part of a query result, a column with names is returned.  I want to apply a function so that the order of first and last name is flipped in my $db results.   What is the most efficient way to accomplish this?

There answer probably lies in using either the foreach function, array_walk or  array_map but I don't know the proper syntax.

This function does the name flip:

```
$name = "Lastname, Firstname";
$names = explode(", ", $name);
$name = $names[1] . " " . $names[0];
```

The $query is similar to this:

```
$query0="SELECT #__1pgndata.White,  #__1pgndata.Black,  #__1pgndata.ECO, #__1pgndata.Result, #__1pgndata.EventDate, #__1pgndata.Id
  FROM `#__1pgndata` Where #__1pgndata.Id > 155 LIMIT 30"
```

White and Black are columns for player names (need to be flipped) and correspond to the color of chess pieces.   The columns in question are $ginfo->White and $ginfo->Black.

Comment: Bringing an example of such a a string would greatly help you

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: It would help if you could post the code where you're actually *using* `$ginfo`, especially any loops already involved.

Answer (score 2):

if you are speaking about the order they are put in the array , you can just select them reversed (for example SELECT first_name, last_name, ..  FROM users...) but I suggest you use mysql_fetch_array, that way you will be able to access them as you wish (with $row['first_name'], $row['last_name'] in whatever order you want)

Comment: Both first and last are in the same column.  See string manipulation code in my edited question.

Comment: you can't apply the function directly on a db resultset, you need to either fetch the resutlt into an array, and apply the function while you are doing that (so $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); flip($row); - where flip is your function and $row is passed by reference) or apply it after you've feched it with array_walk($rows, 'flip')

Comment: If my resulting query is called $ginfo and the column in question is $ginfo->White, what is the syntax for array_walk that will work for me?

Comment: It depends what you mean by $ginfo and how you store your database info in PHP . I was telling you earlier about a case where you store all your rows in an array , and each row is an array. but I can see you are using objects, so I can't tell for your case. 
If you want an sql solution (probably this is the best way to do it): 
SELECT SUBSTRING(name,1, LOCATE(",",name)-1 ) AS firstname, SUBSTRING(name, LOCATE(",",name)+1, LENGTH(name)-LOCATE(",",name)) AS lastname FROM table  
should do the trick

Comment: $ginfo is a mysql database query result.

Comment: $ginfo doesn't have the row data, it's merely a link to a query result stored on the server. To actually get the row data as an array, you need to loop over one of the various `fetch` functions to grab each row of the result set.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a [plenty of string functions](http://php.net/strings). You can use any you wish

Comment: See string manipulation code in my edited question.  I want to apply it to an entire column or as a foreach loop.  I can't get it to work.

Comment: There answer probably lies in using either the foreach function, array_walk or  array_map but I don't know the proper syntax.

Comment: @ggg well I bet you re using this query result somehow. Using `while` loop I suppose. So, put this code inside of while loop. You already know every bit of the solution. Try to put it together. Try to think!

Answer (score 0):

would you provide your db code?

```
$query0="SELECT  #__1pgndata.Black, #__1pgndata.White,  #__1pgndata.ECO, #__1pgndata.Result, #__1pgndata.EventDate, #__1pgndata.Id
```

FROM `#__1pgndata` Where #__1pgndata.Id > 155 LIMIT 30"

you can use like this also right.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to replicate the functionality using the [MySQL String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html). The most likely candidate would probably a combination of `LOCATE()` to find the position of the `', '` and then a pair of `SUBSTR()` calls to get the portions before and after, then using `CONCAT()` to put them back together.

Comment: I have the function, see my question. The problem is coming up with the syntax so that the function applies to the entire column.